# Load tests on Mule 3.5

Tags: mule, mule-component

I am running load tests with JMeter, and responds well Mule with 12 threads but with 14 not responding, and then I have to restart. Someone help me.

And no errors, the log stands still.

The configuration of the components

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="ActiveMQ" brokerURL="${org.xyz.esb.jms.url}" 
                        validateConnections="true" createMultipleTransactedReceivers="true" 
                        numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="30" doc:name="AMQ BE">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="30" maxThreadsIdle="5" doThreading="false" threadTTL="20000" poolExhaustedAction="DISCARD_OLDEST" />
    <reconnect frequency="5000"/>                   
</jms:activemq-connector>                       

<jms:activemq-connector name="ActiveMQLog" brokerURL="${org.xyz.esb.jms.url}" validateConnections="false" disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="true" doc:name="AMQ Log"/>

<db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Cache"  doc:name="MySQL Configuration" dataSource-ref="dataSMule"/>
<db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Cache2"  doc:name="MySQL Configuration" dataSource-ref="dataSMule2"/>


<vm:connector   name="vm_cnn_op" validateConnections="false" 
                createMultipleTransactedReceivers="true" 
                numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="30">
    <vm:queue-profile maxOutstandingMessages="500" />
</vm:connector>

<configuration doc:name="conf_ssb">
    <default-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="30" maxThreadsIdle="5" doThreading="false" threadTTL="20000" poolExhaustedAction="DISCARD_OLDEST" />
</configuration>

<flow name="agent-xdf-main" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    ...
</flow>
```

--- this is the execution of jstack

```
2015-09-18 23:03:10
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.71-b01 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff231c14800 nid=0xdd07 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff231afa000 nid=0xab07 waiting on condition [0x0000000155c24000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000014c287758> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:359)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:942)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"[esb-xyz-r4].HTTP_HTTPS_4.receiver.15" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff2320ce000 nid=0xdb03 in Object.wait() [0x0000000159fb9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000001469fa630> (a org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1118)
    - locked <0x00000001469fa630> (a org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.AbandonedObjectPool.borrowObject(AbandonedObjectPool.java:79)
    WorkerContext.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"[esb-xyz-r4].http.request.dispatch.8085.14" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff2320cd800 nid=0xd903 waiting on condition [0x0000000159ec0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000001468c24a8> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:834)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:994)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1303)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:236)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageProcessTemplate.awaitTermination(HttpMessageProcessTemplate.java:492)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver.processRequest(HttpMessageReceiver.java:60)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpRequestDispatcherWork.run(HttpRequestDispatcherWork.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Statistics Thread" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22b810800 nid=0x2b0b waiting on condition [0x0000000155a1e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000010f1d9a00> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1090)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"__DEFAULT__" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22afc3800 nid=0x2c0b in Object.wait() [0x0000000154de6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000010f1cea50> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    - locked <0x000000010f1cea50> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"Abandoned connection cleanup thread" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22b772000 nid=0x2f07 in Object.wait() [0x0000000151c47000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x000000010eb6f1a8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:41)

"[esb-xyz-r4].Mule.01" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22b759800 nid=0x6203 waiting on condition [0x0000000156559000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000010ec222b0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.pollFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:519)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.poll(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:682)
    at org.mule.context.notification.ServerNotificationManager.run(ServerNotificationManager.java:267)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"[esb-xyz-r4].log4j.config.monitor" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22b40b800 nid=0x6003 waiting on condition [0x0000000156456000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.log4j.ArtifactAwareRepositorySelector$ConfigWatchDog.run(ArtifactAwareRepositorySelector.java:411)

"[default].processing.time.monitor" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22b6d7800 nid=0x5e03 in Object.wait() [0x0000000154bb5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000010ed30460> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x000000010ed30460> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at org.mule.management.stats.DefaultProcessingTimeWatcher$ProcessingTimeChecker.run(DefaultProcessingTimeWatcher.java:76)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"[default].Mule.01" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22adc2000 nid=0x5c03 waiting on condition [0x00000001551c4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000010e1efb40> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.pollFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:519)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.poll(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:682)
    at org.mule.context.notification.ServerNotificationManager.run(ServerNotificationManager.java:267)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"[default].log4j.config.monitor" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22ad5f000 nid=0x5a03 waiting on condition [0x00000001550c1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.log4j.ArtifactAwareRepositorySelector$ConfigWatchDog.run(ArtifactAwareRepositorySelector.java:411)

"[default].log4j.config.monitor" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22ad03800 nid=0x5807 waiting on condition [0x0000000154fbe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.log4j.ArtifactAwareRepositorySelector$ConfigWatchDog.run(ArtifactAwareRepositorySelector.java:411)

"Mule.log.slf4j.ref.handler" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22b1e4800 nid=0x5103 in Object.wait() [0x0000000154944000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000010e1ea228> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x000000010e1ea228> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at org.mule.module.logging.LoggerReferenceHandler$1.run(LoggerReferenceHandler.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Mule.log.clogging.ref.handler" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22aced800 nid=0x4f03 in Object.wait() [0x0000000154841000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000010e1e8898> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x000000010e1e8898> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at org.mule.module.logging.LoggerReferenceHandler$1.run(LoggerReferenceHandler.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Mule.system.log4j.config.monitor" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22acc2800 nid=0x4d03 waiting on condition [0x000000015473e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.log4j.ArtifactAwareRepositorySelector$ConfigWatchDog.run(ArtifactAwareRepositorySelector.java:411)

"DestroyJavaVM" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22b0e0000 nid=0x1303 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Wrapper-Connection" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22b0d7800 nid=0x4903 runnable [0x0000000153cba000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:265)
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.handleSocket(WrapperManager.java:3737)
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.run(WrapperManager.java:4084)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Wrapper-Control-Event-Monitor" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22b072800 nid=0x4503 waiting on condition [0x0000000153ab4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$3.run(WrapperManager.java:731)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22a8a8000 nid=0x4103 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22a87d000 nid=0x3f03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22b001000 nid=0x3d03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22a8a2800 nid=0x300f runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22b010800 nid=0x2903 in Object.wait() [0x0000000151b03000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000010e120260> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x000000010e120260> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22a85e800 nid=0x2703 in Object.wait() [0x0000000151a00000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000010e11fd18> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
    - locked <0x000000010e11fd18> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"VM Thread" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22a85c000 nid=0x2503 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22a818800 nid=0x2103 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22b00a000 nid=0x2303 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff22a8b1000 nid=0x4303 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 471
```

Comment: Can you explain the steps on what you are doing with some mule config file if possible. This will help us to give you exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're not providing any info so here is a general answer: make sure Mule's thread pools are properly configured.

Comment: and I put a little more information, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing http calls, you can use jetty-inbound instead of http-inbound transport which handles more load.

No matter the transport you use, you should tune the threading profile and run jmeter from a different host.

Also you can check more info on the [performance-tuning-guide](https://www.mulesoft.com/lp/whitepaper/soa/performance-tuning-guide).

Answer (score 0):

In general, these kind of issues needs to be figured out using narrow-down approach. Since there is no clarity on what each thread is doing as part of testing in your problem statement here are couple of pointers which you can try

- check whether JMeter has enough resources or not (check using Resource Monitor utility - CPU, Memory)
- server reaction to requests
- Try hitting the application url from same machine where jmeter is running. This will show whether there is a problem from jmeter or not
- If point 3 fails, try hitting the application url from server / someother machine if it works its a problem with jmeter & machine resources else server
- See memory allocation to jmeter. Default allocations will be very less

There are some tips. Please try if possible